# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _module) is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules, parceljs

I'm using parcel, and I'm trying to use ES6 import and export syntax. Parcel seems to run babel underground, I'm very new to it. When openimn the index.html placed on "dist" folder it does not render well and shows this error in console: "Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _module.importedHi) is not a function"

This the code in the exporting JS file:

```
export const importedHi = document.write("Hello world")
```

And this is the code of the main.js:

```
import {importedHi} from "./module1";

importedHi()
```

And this is the script im using in index.html

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

What do I have to configure so that this works properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.write` returns `undefined`, so `importedHi` is `undefined`, and `importedHi()` throws an error. You probably wanted to export a *function* that calls `document.write`, eg:

```
export const importedHi = () => document.write("Hello world");
```

Still, if you're at the point that you can use modules and bundlers, you should probably use more modern methods of manipulating the DOM, like `createElement` / `appendChild` and such, perhaps something like

```
export const importedHi = () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello world'));
};
```

Comment: `You probably wanted to export a function that calls document.write` to be fair, nobody wants to export a function that calls `document.write` :p

Comment: Well, for learning porpuses it is valid, dont you think? Or do you want me to build the new facebook app in order to learn?

Comment: You *can* use `document.write` if you want, it's just not a good idea - many linters warn against it, it can be a form of `eval`, and it will unintuitively replace the current document if the document has already loaded. There's no use learning it IMO - it shouldn't be used, use other DOM methods like the ones I mentioned or `insertAdjacentHTML`. (Similarly, there are many cases where you *can* use `eval`, but it's ugly and can be unsafe, so generally you shouldn't, if you can avoid it)

Comment: I fixed it as @CertainPerformance recommended, however, I still get the same error.. I'm having serious problems implementing import / export :(

Comment: @JulioRodríguez I can't reproduce, it appears to be working as desired for me https://codesandbox.io/s/72v4pjk07q